# Creating xml from with java

Tags: java, xml

I need your expertise once again. I have a java class that searches a directory for xml files (displays the files it finds in the eclipse console window), applies the specified xslt to these and sends the output to a directory.

What I want to do now is create an xml containing the file names and file format types. The format should be something like;

```
<file>
      <fileName>         </fileName>
      <fileType>       </fileType>
</file>

<file>
     <fileName>         </fileName>
     <fileType>       </fileType>
</file>
```

Where for every file it finds in the directory it creates a new `<file>`.

Any help is truely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at DOM and ECS. The following example was adapted to you requirements from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1044810.html#):

```
XMLDocument document = new XMLDocument();
for (File f : files) {
    document.addElement( new XML("file")
        .addXMLAttribute("fileName", file.getName())
        .addXMLAttribute("fileType", file.getType())
      )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use an XML library. There are plenty around, and the third party ones are almost all easier to use than the built-in DOM API in Java. Last time I used it, [JDom](http://jdom.org/) was pretty good. (I haven't had to do much XML recently.)

Something like:

```
Element rootElement = new Element("root"); // You didn't show what this should be
Document document = new Document(rootElement);

for (Whatever file : files)
{
    Element fileElement = new Element("file");
    fileElement.addContent(new Element("fileName").addContent(file.getName());
    fileElement.addContent(new Element("fileType").addContent(file.getType());
}

String xml = XMLOutputter.outputString(document);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the StringBuilder approach suggested by Vinze, but one caveat is that you will need to make sure your filenames contain no special XML characters, and escape them if they do (for example replace < with &lt;, and deal with quotes appropriately).

In this case it probably doesn't arise and you will get away without it, however if you ever port this code to reuse in another case, you may be bitten by this. So you might want to look at an XMLWriter class which will do all the escaping work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well just use a StringBuilder :

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(File f : files) {
    builder.append("<file>\n\t<fileName>").append(f.getName).append("</fileName>\n)";
    [...]
}
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Comment: Bad idea. If you have any filenames with characters which need escaping in XML, you'll have trouble. There's a reason why there are XML libraries...

Comment: That's right... I'm used to do it for "simple" data export but I always know what are the escaping issues...

Comment: Given a decent API, using a library results in code which is just as simple - if not simpler - and a *lot* more robust, IMO.

Comment: Yes, but IF you don't have any library at hand, AND the XML is very simple, I'd rather not depend on yet another library.

Often you will need such a library anyway, and in that case you should use it.

Comment: Yes... I used that more for "single shot" use... for reusable code and "core functionalities" (such as save/load) I also use an API :)

Comment: I would only do this for code I didn't expect to use ever again - i.e. never going into code control. The benefits of having a robust solution almost always outweigh the costs of adding a small library.